# Move pointer in arrays with C

Tags: arrays, c, file

Is there anyway I can move the pointer in the array. So, like you move where the pointer is pointing at in the array. For files, I know that you can use `fseek` with something like `fread` to only copy from a specific location.

I'm trying to copy parts of an array into different files. With `fwrite`, it doesn't give the option to start from a specific location, so I'll need to move the pointer to somewhere in the array, then copy a part of the array into a file.

Comment: You can use `&array[index]` to get a pointer to an element of the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sure you can move a pointer. Say we have an array of ints

```
int arr[50];
```

set p to point at the first element

```
int*p = &arr[0];
```

now move it along by 10

```
p += 10;
```

p now points at arr[10];

Addition on a pointer is defined as incrementing the pointer by n times the size of each elements. Subtraction works too. Be aware of going off either end though, C wont look out for you. Ie this

```
p += 500;
```

will compile but will lead to undefined behavior if you try to use p;

Comment: Ok, thanks. I didn't realize that you could use `&` to receive the pointer to an element of an array. That makes lots of sense.

Comment: @AlexZhao you can do `int*p=&arr[10]`

Comment: Yes, except that I can keep incrementing to keep pointing to different elements of the array. Ok, thanks.

Comment: @pm100 Actually, you can just write `int*p = arr;` instead of  `int*p = &arr[0];`